# TYPE_ALIGNMENT(LARGE_INTEGER) incorrect when building against Win10 SDK

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi, c-preprocessor

I am running into issues with this assertion in the Win 10 SDK for Winnt.h, when upgrading from Win8.1 a C file which #includes winnt.h:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
> Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h(2487,1): error C2118: negative
> subscript

```
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
static_assert(__alignof(LARGE_INTEGER) == 8, "Windows headers require the default packing option. Changing this can lead to memory corruption."
" This diagnostic can be disabled by building with WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH defined.");
#elif _MSC_VER >= 1300
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4116)
C_ASSERT(TYPE_ALIGNMENT(LARGE_INTEGER) == 8);    <========= LN2487
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
#endif
```

The error is simply telling me the `CASSERT` failed, but I have explicitly set /Zp8 and that made no difference.

### So I hacked Winnt.h:

```
// Much of the Windows SDK assumes the default packing of structs.
#if !defined(WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH) && !defined(__midl) && !defined(MIDL_PASS) && !defined(SORTPP_PASS) && !defined(RC_INVOKED)
#if defined(__cplusplus) && (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
static_assert(__alignof(LARGE_INTEGER) == 8, "Windows headers require the default packing option. Changing this can lead to memory corruption."
    " This diagnostic can be disabled by building with WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH defined.");
#elif _MSC_VER >= 1300
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4116)
#pragma pack(show)
C_ASSERT(TYPE_ALIGNMENT(LARGE_INTEGER) == 8);
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
#endif
```

Test code:

```
#pragma pack(show)
#include "LibraryHeader.h" //somehow includes Windows.h
#pragma pack(show)
```

Now I get result:

> ```
> value of pragma pack(show) == 8
> value of pragma pack(show) == 4
> value of pragma pack(show) == 8
> ```

So it seems the mess of 3rd party headers we are using must be causing this.  Which is weird because it worked against the 8.1 SDK, *and* because the header itself *explcitly tells* us we must have 8-byte packing/alignment set in the compiler.

I guess **the question** comes down to: is there any way the W10 SDK is *causing* this given no code has changed and it compiles against W8.1 SDK? Or, has it always been like this and the W8.1 SDK failed to check?

Comment: Are you including winnt.h directly or is it included because you're including Windows.h? Are you using precompiled headers?

Comment: *So I hacked Winnt.h:*  Nice.  So what third party header is breaking it?  So we know to avoid that product... ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am going to have to find out, I just need to such for `#pragma pack` right? As I've said, it worked before though.

Comment: Does the accepted answer of this Question help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163044/after-installing-vs2008-i-get-a-compile-error-in-winnt-h

Comment: @engf-010 I think it's a separate issue although I can test on a machine which _only_ has Windows 10 SDK to make sure

Comment: @AndrewHenle so I compared `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\8.1\um\winnt.h` and that section I pasted in my question _doesn't exist_ in 8.1. I can confirm it does temporarily change to 4 in both cases. (I'd post online links if I knew them)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section of Winnt.h posted in the question from Win 10 SDK is missing from the Win8.1 SDK, which implies the issue was always there but unreported.

Microsoft provide a way to disable this check, using the `WINDOWS_IGNORE_PACKING_MISMATCH` preprocessor definition.

For those interested, I verified in the library that it was indeed pushing/popping packing values for specific machine architectures. I couldn't tell why but that was as deep as I was willing to go!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue with old C source code that compiled fine with Visual Studio 2017 and earlier but issued the same error with Visual Studio 2019 using the Windows 10 SDK.

My problem was a couple of projects in the solution had explicitly set the Struct Member Alignment compiler option to `/Zp1` which resulted in the `C_ASSERT` failing with the somewhat opaque error of "negative subscript" from include file winnt.h.

This could also be caused by using a pack `pragma` prior to the include file winnt.h being included or processed by the Preprocessor.  See [Negative Subscript in winnt.h](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/negative-subscript-in-winnth-5/1533745) posted into the Visual Studio Developer Community by someone who was doing that.

I changed the option from `/Zp1` to `Default` and the project compiled fine.

See also [Static assertion failed with "Windows headers require the default packing option..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570681/static-assertion-failed-with-windows-headers-require-the-default-packing-option) and see as well [ERROR Windows headers require the default packing option on winnt.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811562/error-windows-headers-require-the-default-packing-option-on-winnt-h)

See also this Visual Studio Developer Community post, [C2118 error with Windows Kits 10.0.18362.0 in winnt.h](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/c2118-error-with-windows-kits-100183620-in-winnth/739697), which several posts mentioning this seems to be due to a change in the Windows 10 SDK beginning with 10.0.18362.0.

This probably means that some of my structs which depend on a `/Zp1` with a byte member alignment are going to create data errors so I have to track those down and use `#pragma pack(push, 1)` and `#pragma pack(pop)` where appropriate.

I'm adding this answer in case someone else needs a reminder about this possibility.

[image: screenshot of project Properties dialog showing the Struct Member Alignment C/C++ compiler option]